# Spatial Join takes very long time on two small datasets using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I have two datasets:

- A is a hexagon grid and has 19089 rows
- B contains linestrings and has 18641 rows

I want to know, which linestrings are within which hexagon.

```sql
WITH bufferedB AS (
        SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_Union(geom), 15) AS geom, foo FROM B
        GROUP BY foo
    ), hexB AS (
        SELECT A.geom, bb.foo, A.id FROM A
            LEFT JOIN bufferedB AS bb
                ON ST_Intersects(A.geom, bb.geom)
    ) UPDATE A
        SET x = hexB.foo
        FROM hexB 
        WHERE hexB.id = A.id;
```

This is the `EXPLAIN` output:

```
"Update on someTable  (cost=1917240.00..1944664.69 rows=1821950 width=252)"
"  ->  Merge Join  (cost=1917240.00..1944664.69 rows=1821950 width=252)"
"        Merge Cond: (A.id = someTable.id)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=1915225.84..1915273.56 rows=19089 width=86)"
"              Sort Key: A.id"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3157.14..1913868.57 rows=19089 width=86)"
"                    Join Filter: st_intersects(A.geom, bb.geom)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on someTable A  (cost=0.00..656.89 rows=19089 width=162)"
"                    ->  Materialize  (cost=3157.14..3357.24 rows=4 width=108)"
"                          ->  Subquery Scan on bl  (cost=3157.14..3357.22 rows=4 width=108)"
"                                ->  HashAggregate  (cost=3157.14..3357.18 rows=4 width=42)"
"                                      Group Key: B.foo"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on B (cost=0.00..780.41 rows=18641 width=100)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=2014.16..2061.88 rows=19089 width=170)"
"              Sort Key: someTable.id"
"           

 ->  Seq Scan on someTable  (cost=0.00..656.89 rows=19089 width=170)"
```

Both tables, A and B, have an index.

Comment: please add the `explain` output for you query, and do you have any indexes?

Comment: @IanTurton I have added the explain

Comment: Looks like you need an index (or two)

Comment: @IanTurton I just added it, both tables (A and B) have an index.

Comment: Use ST_DWithin instead of ST_Buffer

Comment: @IanTurton Could the problem be, that I do a `SELECT A.geom, bb.foo, A.id FROM A` and then perform an ` UPDATE A` on the same table?

Comment: @MikeT I like that idea, but it does not make the query faster. I runs and runs and runs.

Comment: did adding the indexes change the `explain` result?

Comment: The `bufferedB` CTE is very expensive when ST_DWithin is svailable, but you're going to get  multiple updates to each A row if any lines are near each other, so I question the appropriateness of the UPDATE.

Comment: why are you buffering the linestrings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is overly complicated and highly inefficient - for plenty of reasons, e.g.

- CTE's are no *nice-to-have*'s
- buffers are worst practice for proximity searches
- geometry unions are extremely costly

Avoid these as much as possible, and explore the built in features first.

An `UPDATE` visits every row (within a possible filter) in sequence and provides read and write access to its values from within the full range of correlated expressions.

Here, your intentions seem to be simply:

```
UPDATE "A" AS a
  SET  x = h.foo
FROM   hexB AS b
WHERE  ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
;
```